# Явная специализация в классе

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, g++

Как сделать, чтобы этот код, работающий в MSVS, заработал на g++?

```
template <class A, const int options=1>
class B{        
    A a;
     
    B(){
            Init<options>();
    }
     
    template <int option> void Init();
    template<> void Init<0>(){}
    template<> void Init<1>(){ a.key=1; }        
};
```

Answer (score 1):

В этом куске кода:

```
B(){
            Init<options>();
    }
```

Опция не увидится! Пояснение читайте [Explicit specialization in non-namespace scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052579/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope) и  еще [explicit (full) template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
template <class A>
class Base
{
protected:
    A a;
};

template <class A, const int options=1>
class B : Base<A>
{
    using Base<A>::a;
};

template<class A>
class B<A, 1> : public Base<A>
{
    using Base<A>::a;
    B() { Init(); }
    void Init()
    {
        a.key = 1;
    }
};
```

[Проверка](http://ideone.com/PKeWX1).

Comment: Это слишком закручено. Придется на каждый вариант options написать свой класс. Есть другой вариант, как в зависимости от значения опции выполнять код, или нет?

Comment: @mikelsv:

* Вы можете вынести общий код в `Base`, так что классы будут со всего одним методом + конструктор. Можно даже выкинуть метод и положить инициализацию в конструктор, если вам хочется.
* Вы не сможете перегрузить лишь один метод в зависимости от `options`, т. к. в C++ нет частичной специализации методов. Так что всё равно придётся делать по классу на каждый вариант options. Sorry for that.